# Refactoring a big file in emacs

Tags: emacs, refactoring, bookmarks

I'm refactoring a big piece of code in one file in Emacs.

What is the best way to simplify jumping to several places in a big emacs buffer?
Currently I'm using search (C-S) and custom comments - "markers".
This becoming quiclkly unreliable.

Ideally I would like to have the same file open in several buffers, so I can switch between them using C-X B.

What are your solutions?

Comment: Registers are great but a little to general. Just like bookmarks. It is just to cumbersome to have to use 4 chrods just to jump to the other one.

Comment: You could always use custom bindings to reduce the number of key-presses. To be honest, I usually get around okay using the local and global mark rings, although now that I'm thinking about it, something analogous for marker registers would be handy -- convert to a ring, and provide easy cycling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- It seems that what you are looking for is [Indirect-Buffers](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Indirect-Buffers.html#Indirect-Buffers).
- Personally, I find that splitting my window (`C-x 2`) is a great help.
- Also [bookmarks](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookMarks) come to mind.

Comment: When using clone-indirect-buffer (usually with `C-x 4 c`), I sometimes find it useful to also narrow the cloned buffer to the region I am interested in with `C-x n n`

Answer (score 3):

See [Emacs Bookmarks](http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/emacs-19.34/html_node/emacs_68.html).

Going to a particular bookmark switches to the correct buffer automatically (a bookmark is associated to a buffer).

Answer (score 2):

Registers are useful for marking and jumping to positions. If you only have a small number of spots to mark and remember at any time, it may be faster to use single-character registers than named bookmarks.

- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>SPC</kbd> runs `point-to-register`
- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> runs `jump-to-register`

When prompted for the register, you can type any character.

Answer (score 0):

Use [autonamed bookmarks](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#AutonamedBookmarks).  No need to specify a name each time you create a bookmark -- just hit a key.  Like using <kbd>C-SPC</kbd> to set a mark, but bookmarks are (by default) persistent; marks are not.

With [***Bookmark+***](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) you can also organize bookmarks (including autonamed bookmarks) into sets etc. Tag them in various ways, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Visual bookmarks is extremely useful for this case. You can get it [from here](https://github.com/joodland/bm) or install it using

```
M-x package-install RET bm
```

and add this to your config.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") 'bm-toggle)
(global-set-key (kbd "<f7>") 'bm-next)
(global-set-key (kbd "<f6>") 'bm-previous)
```

Now, any where in your file press `f5` and it creates a mark there. If you want to remove it, just press `f5` again.

You can create any number of markers and now using `f6` & `f7` you can quickly go to any point you want.